# Android - Push Notification in Background Service c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, service

I am working on Android `C#` app which tracks user's stocks price. I want the app to push notification (in background) whenever the value of stock increase 1%. I have searched online and I know I need to use `BroadcastReceiver`and `Services` but I am not able to implement my own code and I haven't found a tutorial or a published exemple on how to do it. I am sure the solution will be very easy but Ia m not able to get it. 
So again, I want to push notification in bachground whenever the `var price` goes up by 1%.. Please Help me to do so.. Thank you

Here's what I have till now:

```
     [BroadcastReceiver]
public class MyReciver : Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided a demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/BackgroundServiceToIncPrice).

In my project, there are two button, the first one is to register the broadcast, and start a service for your app. The second one is to imitate increase the price, you can change it base upon yours. I have add comments in my project.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers) is how to use the `BroadcasetReceiver` in Xamarin.Android. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/) is how to use the `Service`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications) is how to push a notification in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. But what I want to do is to keep tracking the price (which I am getting from a `URL` using `JSON`) in the `BackGround` and when the price is up 1% I want to send a notification to the user.

Comment: Hi, your question not mention the URL. It should be another question, I suggest you open another thread to ask for tracking the price.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I am tracking a stock's price in the BackGround and if it increased 1% then I want to notify the user about that increase. Would you please edit your code to do so ?

Comment: Hi, I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, @Wassim01, I have update my demo on github, please check it.

Comment: not yet, I ll try it tomorrow :) Sure, I ll let you know about the results